# object access in objective-c EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, object, exc-bad-access

I've got NSMutableArray filled with custom class called "Audio"
It is with this properties:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *artist;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *duration;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *audio_id;
```

First my action is print them in UITableView. This is going without any problem.
But second action, showing “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”, when i want to access audio_id property, to pass it into other method as param:

```
Audio *audio = [musicList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self dosomething:audio.audio_id];
```

Here is: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
Please, help, anybody:)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your "second action"? Does the printing happen before your second action? Do they happen in the same roundtrip? Can printing access the `audio_id` variable fine? A little more code would help.

Comment: Is the mutable array containing the Audio objects properly retained somewhere?

Comment: First action is put data from musicList to UITableView, second action is method, that gets object from musicList, and passes audio_id as param into another method "[self.dosomething:audio.audio_id]"
Second action called when i press button.
"musicList" is NSMutableArray;

Comment: In that case, the array is probably being released at some point after the printing but before the button press. What would help is: the code that shows the declaration and population of the musicList array.

Comment: Guven, no, i can access this array. Because i print this array many times without retaining.

Comment: Why is it that people seem to think that their problems can be diagnosed with minimal code these days?

Comment: Tim Dean, I get Audio properties from xml file. XMLParser parse my xml with Audio information, and pushes each Audio object into array...When it's done, i copy xmlParsers array with audio object, into musicList array using musicList = [xmlParser.audioArray mutableCopy];

Comment: I can print this audio_id in NSLog before getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you debug better:

```
Audio *audio = [musicList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if(audio){
    [self doSomething:audio.audio_id];
}
else if(musicList){ NSLog(@"musicList is not nil and has a count of %d.",[musicList count]); }
else{ NSLog(@"musicList is nil and audio is nil, something is getting released too soon."); }
```